# i did not comprehend sum(iterable[, start]) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum

I have the following:

```
list = [32,12,43,24,65,16]
```

and I'm trying to sum the elements inside that list excluding the first element, I want to sum (12,43...)
I have tried:

```
sum(list[,1])
sum(list,[1])
sum(list,1)
```

but none of them seems to work. The documentation shows `sum(iterable[, start])`.

Comment: Start is the _start value_, it is summed together with the rest. It's not that useful.

Comment: `sum(iterable, x) == sum(iterable, 0) + x == sum(iterable) + x`

Comment: @RemcoGerlich The `start` argument is useful for summing non-numbers, e.g. `sum([[1,2],[3,4],[5]], [])`. (`itertools.chain.from_iterable()` is better for iterables, but the point still stands, e.g. for summing custom objects)

Comment: @marcelm: ahh, thanks, I was missing something obviously

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`start` is an optional additional element to add.

```
>>> sum([1, 2], 4)
7
>>> sum([1, 2])
3
>>> sum([], 4)
4
```

To exclude 1st element while summing use this:

```
>>> list = [32,12,43,24,65,16]
>>> sum(list[1:])
160
```